Everytime i add the Sqflite plugin in dependencies i get an error at run time
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\hhh25\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\hhh25.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\hhh25.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             15.0s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have tried the following:

Installing older versions, still doesn't work
deleting the sqflite dependency , it works

Here are the results of flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.24.4 on channel stable at C:\fluterdev\flutter_windows_3.24.3-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 603104015d (12 days ago), 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
    • Engine revision db49896cf2
    • Dart version 3.5.4
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\hhh25\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[√] VS Code (version 1.95.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\hhh25\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.100.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM M215G (mobile) • RZ8R80P4K2W • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.92
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 130.0.2849.68

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

Here is my dependencies file:
name: mabi3ati
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.3

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  sqflite: ^2.2.0
  intl: ^0.19.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


Add your dependencies code please!

@Murtaza i just added the dependencies file, im using sqflite 2.2.0 in this instance, but i tried using the the latest version before and had the same problem

Try to upgrade flutter SDK and update the Android studio to latest version and use latest version of the sqflite: 2.4.0.

@Murtaza both flutter and android studio are up to date; the problem has to do with the java jdk

I fixed it by

downloading Java JDK 17 and then specifying the path with the
following command: flutter config --jdk-dir 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17'

I'm still not sure why newer JDK didn't work though.

I found out the same happens using path_provider: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/156558#issuecomment-2446956094
solution summary:
gradle-wrapper.properties:
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
# Updated to 8.9
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-all.zip

settings.gradle:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    /// id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    /// Updated to 8.7.1
    id "com.android.application" version "8.7.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

Notes added here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/troubleshooting.md#could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-sqflite_androidandroidjdkimage
(unfortunately there is not much I can to on my side to prevent this issue, maybe the flutter android template should be upgraded)
